# Export SQLite table which contains JSON column without double escaping

Tags: json, sqlite

Let a SQLite table be built like :

```
create table t(id, j json);
insert into t values (1, '{"name": "bob"}');
insert into t values (2, '{"name": "alice", "age":20, "hobbies":[ "a", "b", "c"] }');
```

What's the easiest way to export the whole table as valid JSON, without JSON strings being escaped?

```
sqlite> .mode json
sqlite> select id, j from t;
[{"id":1,"j":"{\"name\": \"bob\"}"},
{"id":2,"j":"{\"name\": \"alice\", \"age\":20, \"hobbies\":[ \"a\", \"b\", \"c\"] }"}] -- WRONG!
```

JSON column may vary. Couldn't do it with `json_extract` function. Expecting parsable JSON,

```
[{"id":1,"j":{"name": "bob"}},
{"id":2,"j":{"name": "alice", "age":20, "hobbies":[ "a", "b", "c"] }}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions [`json()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jmini) to remove escaping from the column `j` and [`json_group_array()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jgrouparray) to aggregate:

```
select json_group_array(json_object('id', id, 'j', json(j))) result
from t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=32b3da57b90fb074f37ea25f0b08567c).
Results:

| result |
| --- |
| [{"id":1,"j":{"name":"bob"}},{"id":2,"j":{"name":"alice","age":20,"hobbies":["a","b","c"]}}] |

Comment: Thank you very much! works perfectly, no need to use JSON mode.